# How to connect to a clustered Azure Redis cache in redis-rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure, redis, azure-redis-cache

I am attempting to use the Ruby Redis client [redis-rb](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb) to connect to an Azure Redis Cache configured for clustering.

#### What I've tried:

I have used this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41761958/how-to-setup-azure-redis-cache-with-rails) to successfully connect to a non-clustered Azure Redis Cache. I can also use this to connect to a clustered Azure Redis Cache, which correctly reports `MOVED` when I attempt to get or set keys:

```
Redis::CommandError (MOVED 1234 address_here:port_here)
```

I have seen this [documentation](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb#cluster-support) for creating the connection with `cluster`:

> Nodes can be passed to the client as an array of connection URLs.
>
> ```
> nodes = (7000..7005).map { |port| "redis://127.0.0.1:#{port}" }
> redis = Redis.new(cluster: nodes)
> ```
>
> You can also specify the options as a Hash. The options are the same as for a single server connection.
>
> ```
> (7000..7005).map { |port| { host: '127.0.0.1', port: port } }
> ```

I have used these examples to build an example against the single available DNS endpoint that fails with the following error:

```
irb(main):024:0> client = Redis.new(cluster: ["redis://my-redis-cluster.redis.cache.windows.net:6379"])
...
Redis::CannotConnectError (Redis client could not connect to any cluster nodes)
```

I've tried each variant of this listed in the documentation, with the same results.

#### Problem:

Azure Cache for Redis exposes the clustered nodes on a single DNS endpoint, while this redis-rb cluster parameter seems to expect a collection of known node endpoints.

Is it possible to use this library to connect to a clustered Azure Redis Cache? And if so, what would a reproducible example of this look like? If it is not possible with redis-rb, but is possible with another Ruby Redis client, I would also be interested in that solution.

Answer (score 1):

According to Azure offical document [`How to configure Redis clustering for a Premium Azure Cache for Redis`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-how-to-premium-clustering), there are two FAQs which has answered your issues.

**1. [Do all Redis clients support clustering?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-how-to-premium-clustering#do-all-redis-clients-support-clustering)**

> Not all clients support Redis clustering! Please check the documentation for the library you are using, to verify you are using a library and version which support clustering. StackExchange.Redis is one library that does support clustering, in its newer versions. For more information on other clients, see the [Playing with the cluster](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial#playing-with-the-cluster) section of the [Redis cluster tutorial](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial).
>
> The Redis clustering protocol requires each client to connect to each shard directly in clustering mode, and also defines new error responses such as 'MOVED' na 'CROSSSLOTS'. Attempting to use a client that doesn't support clustering with a cluster mode cache can result in a lot of [MOVED redirection exceptions](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec#moved-redirection), or just break your application, if you are doing cross-slot multi-key requests.
>
> ***Note***
>
> If you are using StackExchange.Redis as your client, ensure you are using the latest version of StackExchange.Redis 1.0.481 or later for clustering to work correctly. If you have any issues with move exceptions, see move exceptions for more information.

**2. [How do I connect to my cache when clustering is enabled?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-how-to-premium-clustering#how-do-i-connect-to-my-cache-when-clustering-is-enabled)**

> You can connect to your cache using the same endpoints, ports, and keys that you use when connecting to a cache that does not have clustering enabled. Redis manages the clustering on the backend so you don't have to manage it from your client.

So please try to follow the figure below to use [`redis-rb-cluster`](https://github.com/antirez/redis-rb-cluster) instead of `redis-rb` to connect Azure Redis Cache for clustering enabled as same as non-clustering.

[image]