# Can't connect to clustered Azure Redis Cache with redis-rb gem and public access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure, redis, azure-redis-cache

We've provisioned an Azure Redis Cache server using the Premium tier. The server is clustered, with 2 shards, and the server is configured to allow public access over the public internet through a firewall--allow-listing a set of known IPs.

Deploys of our Rails application two any of these known IPs fail with the error:

```
Redis::CannotConnectError: Redis client could not connect to any cluster nodes
```

Here is our Rails config:

```rb
# application.rb 

if Rails.env.test?
      config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, {
        url: config.nines[:redis_url],
        expires_in: 90.minutes,
        namespace: ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'],
      }
    else
      config.cache_store = :redis_store, {
        namespace:ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'],
        cluster: [ Rails.application.config.nines[:redis_url] ],
        replica: true, # allow reads from replicas
        compress: true,
        compress_threshold: 1024,
        expires_in: 90.minutes
      }
    end
```

The `config.nines[:redis_url]` is set like this: `rediss://:<pw>@<cache-name>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380/0`

Then, we initialize the Redis connection in code like this:

```rb
if Rails.env.test?
  ::Redis.new :url => redis_url, :db => ENV['REDIS_DB']
else
  ::Redis.new(cluster: [ "#{redis_url}" ], db: ENV['REDIS_DB'])
end
```

We're using the `redis-rb` gem and `redis-rails` gem.

If anyone can point out what we're doing wrong, please do share!

Comment: [How to setup Azure Redis cache with Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41761958/how-to-setup-azure-redis-cache-with-rails)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [User Peter Pan - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4989676/peter-pan). Posting your suggestion as answer to help other community members.

You can try below code:

```
# Import the redis library for Ruby
require "redis"
# Create a redis client instance for connecting Azure Redis Cache
# At here, for enabling SSL, set the `:ssl` symbol with the
# symbol value `:true`, see https://github.com/redis/redis-rb#ssltls-support
redis = Redis.new(
:host => '<azure redis cache name>.redis.cache.windows.net',
:port => 6380,
:db => <the db index you selected like 10>,
:password => "<access key>",
:ssl => :true)
# Then, set key `foo` with value `bar` and return `OK`
status = redis.set('foo', 'bar')
puts status  # => OK
# Get the value of key `foo`
foo = redis.get('foo')
puts foo # => bar
```

Reference: [How to setup Azure Redis cache with Rails - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41761958/how-to-setup-azure-redis-cache-with-rails)